# The number of non negative integral solutions of $A+B+C≤10$

Tags: combinatorics

Is $286$ correct? Suggest an approach. I did $\binom{12}{2}+\binom{11}{2}+\cdots + \binom{2}{2}$. I took the approach of considering $n$ similar $0$'s and two $1$'s and then tried different arrangements.

Comment: Stars and bars is an extremely common topic in combinatorics. Did your class not cover this topic yet, or perhaps did you not know the name before?

Answer (score 4):

The number of non- negative integral solutions to $A+B+C\leq10$ is the number of non- negative integral solutions to $$A+B+C+D=10$$which by [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) is $${13\choose3}=286$$
Your approach isn't wrong, in fact, it is equivalent to what I've done here by the [Hockey Stick Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity).

Comment: I think zero also included in the case.

Comment: Uhhh,  I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I was thought about using bars, but not by a name of Hockey-stick identity.